# Collection & Digest of Helpful Questions - Flights and Airfare

Tags: discussion

May I start this an anthology and compendium of ***all*** useful questions for flights , for the benefit of all? What is missing or should be included below?

The motivation is my friend's need to buy a one-way flight from Hong Kong to Toronto, and so we want to read all the germane questions here on Travel SE before payment. Yet I thought to extend our concern towards ***all***  kinds of flights, and not just my friend's. Alas, because I'm new here, the supportive but teeming, number of questions overwhelms me and forbodes the danger of missing some critical material.

**Buying:**
https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/951/13759
https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/36381/13759
https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/16045/13759
[What's the best day of the week to buy airfare?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/11322/13759)
https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/37456/13759
https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/8813/13759

**Roundtrip vs one-way:**
[One-way versus return airfare tickets](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/11501/13759)
https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/18856/13759

**Search for flights or special, unusual combinations or routes**
https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/26888/13759
https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/10297/13759
https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/748/13759
https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/951/13759